# My pc freezes after BIOS?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, amd-ryzen

I just built a new pc with a Ryzen 3600 and a MSI B450 Tomahawk MAX and a gtx 1660 super with 16gb vengance 3000mhz ram with a 400w PSU. Firstly I know about the low PSU but it should work right. Firstly then I built the pc and got it all working it posted and whent to BIOS then I did the usual checked if everything is there ram cpu gpu all shown in hardware monitor. This is where it got confusing I tried to boot off a windows live USB and before it even does anything it freezes like the windows logo shows up with the spinning circle underneath and then freezes I have left it on for ages and it doesn't go. Now I tried another USB which didn't work I used the latest version and used the creation tool as well. Now I had an old hdd whith windows on it and decided to test it and when it booted it would BSOD with a code IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL and I also tried a live usb of pop osu (linux distro) giving me a kernel panic message. Now I updated the bios just in case which didn't do anything and I know the max versions support the 3000 series and the mobo was on the april update so it wasnt even that old. This all happened on wednesday and thursday. It is sunday and on thurdsay i decided to try and use another ram module to see if that was why and same outcome. Now I had an old i3 6100 which I used with the PSU RAM AND GPU and it worked the pc booted this led me to believe it was a mobo or cpu issue and beacuse of this I decided to return them to cll computers through amazon and hopefully getting a refund now I am hoping to buy them again although I am scared that the issue will persist so does anybody think it really was a mobo and/or cpu issue or something else please let me know because im building this for a friend and i need it to work.

Part list for anyone wondering: https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/7g99Qq

Answer (score 0):

First of all use an usb port on the back, if the motherboard has an usb2.0 port try that first.

Also did you that both uefi boot and secureboot are enabled in the bios options?

if the problem persists
I don't really like the media creation tool, I often use Rufus to make my bootable usb drives